# 'Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized' only in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a PowerShell script that works from a local PowerShell but when it runs in a PowerShell task in an Azure DevOps release pipeline it returns `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`.

The user is added as a project member within Azure DevOps and I have also created a Personal Access Token with full access.

```
function Get-HttpBasicHeader([string]$username, [string]$password)
{
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $password)))
    return @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader $userName $password

$url = "https://transpa.vsrm.visualstudio.com/transPA/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=42&definitionEnvironmentId=61&api-version=5.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

What am I doing wrong? Let me know if I should provide any additional information.

Comment: *Let me know if I should provide any additional information.* When posting a question involving code that isn't working, the first thing you're going to be asked to provide is **the code that isn't working**.

Comment: Updated the question with a code snippet.

Comment: How are you providing the authentication token to the script? Have you confirmed that the token is being provided? Also, this line looks suspect but I'm guessing it's just a copy/paste or transcription error: `url = $"..."`. Did you mean `$url = "..."`?

Comment: Yes, that was a copy/paste error. The credentials and other variables are defined as pipeline library variables.

Comment: The password variable was put in secret mode (locked) and I took for granted that it could read the value. But your question ```How are you providing the authentication token to the script?``` made me want to double check so I added a Write-Host and the value was empty until I temporarily changed it to a plain text variable. Then it was successfully read and the script worked even within the release pipeline.

Comment: Yes, that's because non-secret variables are automatically captured as environment variables. Secret variables need to be explicitly added to the environment or passed into the script as parameters. This is for security purposes.